# kill popup or dialog box using command line

Tags: unity, command-line, dialog

I wonder is there a way to kill popup or dialog box by using command line?

Actually I want to kill all the popup as shown in [attached picture](http://postimg.org/image/9dqf8cmu1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `xkill` and then click on a window to kill the PID associated with it. This will *probably* kill all the popups, since they are very likely not forked from the original program.